# Will Google Charge Money If We Implement Android Management API for mobile device management(above 1000 devices)...If So How Much?

Tags: android-management-api

we may give the solution to thousands of customers ...want to know the pricing information.
I would like to know if google charges anything for the spotlight features(special features which are not listed in the api documentation).

Answer (score 0):

To increase your [usage limits](https://developers.google.com/android/management/usage) beyond 1000 devices, you need to join the [Android Enterprise EMM Provider community](https://emm.androidenterprise.dev/)—a closed community where developers can access private documentation and guidance, post questions, and work with Google to bring their solutions to market. As a member of the community, you will also receive support from Google experts.

Comment: is it free after 1000+ devices